# Filter an array of object, if X cannot find looking for Y

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of object and I want to make a filter when a language does not exist use an another one.
For example when I'm searching for the langauge **de** and it is not exist I want to search in this case to language **en**

```
const arrObj = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Zero', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 1, name: 'One', lang: 'en', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Two', lang: 'en', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Three', lang: 'en', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Four', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Five', lang: 'en', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Six', lang: 'hu', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Seven', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
]
```

```
const language = 'de'
```

```
const item = arrObj.filter(e => {
  if (e.lang === language && e.video === 'Trailer') {    
    return e.video === 'Trailer'
  } 
})
```

I've tried with **find** function and with different **if else** statement as well. I'm really stuck with this now.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [logical or operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). Right side of the operator will only be evaluated when there is no trailer in `de` since [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns undefined (which is falsy) when there's no match:

```js
const arrObj = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Zero', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 1, name: 'One', lang: 'en', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Two', lang: 'en', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Three', lang: 'en', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Four', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Five', lang: 'en', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Six', lang: 'hu', video: 'Trailer'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Seven', lang: 'hu', video: 'Clip'},
]
const language = 'de';


const item = arrObj.find(e => e.video == 'Trailer' && e.lang === language)
                || arrObj.find(e => e.video == 'Trailer' && e.lang ===  'en');

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will search using all given keywords until one of them returns some result. If no result is found, returns empty array;

```js
let searchTerms = ["de", "be", "en"]

const arrObj = [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Zero',
        lang: 'hu',
        video: 'Clip'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'One',
        lang: 'en',
        video: 'Clip'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Two',
        lang: 'en',
        video: 'Clip'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Three',
        lang: 'en',
        video: 'Trailer'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Four',
        lang: 'hu',
        video: 'Clip'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'Five',
        lang: 'en',
        video: 'Trailer'
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Six',
        lang: 'hu',
        video: 'Trailer'
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: 'Seven',
        lang: 'hu',
        video: 'Clip'
    },
];


let search = (data, keywords) => {
    let filteredData = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {

        filteredData = data.filter(x => x.lang === keywords[j])
        if (filteredData.length != 0) {
            return filteredData;
        }

    }
    return filteredData;


}

console.log(search(arrObj, searchTerms))
```